# How to control nullability in SELECT INTO for literal-based columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am noticing that when I use this statement, the `Action` column is not nullable:

```
SELECT TOP 0 SerialNumber, 0 [Action] INTO #MyTable FROM FSE_SerialNumber
```

But when I use this statement, the `Action` column is nullable:

```
SELECT TOP 0 SerialNumber, CAST(0 as int) [Action] INTO #MyTable FROM FSE_SerialNumber
```

My reason for creating the table this way is because I don't want the temp table to inherit the collation of SerialNumber from the server default collation or elsewhere. I want it to match the collation of FSE_SerialNumber..SerialNumber.

My question is, can I rely on the cast function giving me a nullable column, or is this not clearly defined and might change. Why does the cast suddenly make the column nullable? Is there a better way (besides comments) to clarify that my intent is to get a nullable column there?

Comment: I don't know that this is documented, but elsewhere I've also seen the technique of using a variable rather than a literal to produce a nullable column.  I suppose it's because the variable (like your expression) has a structure whose metadata permits NULLs, so the new column does as well.  And if you named your variable @NullableInt that could handle your self-documentation issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It looks like a definitive answer is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/7af9edf4-9b26-4a00-b14a-8a6263f22675).  Copying here:

> Metadata is determined based on the source column and expressions used
>   in the SELECT list. Below are the rules:
>
> 1. Any expression that uses a built-in function like SUBSTRING, LEFT, RIGHT etc (except ISNULL) for example is considered as NULLable by the
>      engine. So if you use CAST(somecol as char(8)) then the expression is
>      NULLable
> 2. Literals, constants, global variables like @@DBTS, @@ERROR etc are considered non-NULLable since they return some value always
> 3. If expression is a column then nullability is derived from the source column metadata
>
>    So to make an expression or column in the SELECT list not null then use ISNULL around the column or expression.

So, it looks like you are safe to use your CAST expression.

Answer (score 7):

Quick general hint for `SELECT ... INTO` : use `ISNULL(` with a column and it will be created as a NOT NULL column in the table.

Comment: I will be eternally grateful for this answer. Upvote from me :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, for the best control, you should create your table first. For example:

```
Create Table #MyTable (
   SerialNumber int Not Null, -- or however this is correctly defined.
   Action int Null
)
```

Then, do a Insert Into ... Select From ...

```
Insert Into #MyTable(SerialNumber, Action)
Select SerialNumber, 0
From FSE_SerialNumber
```

Then, there will be no question of what the fields should be.

I know this isn't quite what you asked, but it might be something to consider.

Comment: Problem with this is there's no straightforward way to copy the collation of the SerialNumber column into the temp table then. I was doing it your way and had to change it because of collation problems.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN. I am glad you found a suitable solution, and you are indeed correct that you can not _copy_ the collation when creating a table, but you _can_ explicitly supply it in the Create Table statement (for future reference).

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was wanting the resulting columns of my `Select Into...` to be trimmed to a new data length and to be NOT NULL.

So I was doing

`select left(isnull(col2, ''), 10)...`, which was not working.

The `left/isnull` functions need to be reversed with the isnull as the outermost operation

`select isnull(left(col2, 10), '')...`